# Adding a link to a static file with a custom URL on Symfony

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony1, url-routing

When using Symfony 1.0, is it possible to **create a link to a static file** i.e. a PDF or DOC file and **link to it a custom URL**?

I'd like to add a file e.g. example.pdf to the web/uploads/pdf folder on the server but then link to it with a URL such as: http://www.example.com/docs/old/test/example.pdf

This situation has arisen because some printed documentation from before the development of a new web site points to the specified URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out (with a great deal of help from [this blog post](http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/2009/08/03/serving-pdf-files-through-symfony-controllers/). Thanks [Thaberkern](http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/author/thaberkern/))

Create a route to grab the file name:

```
legacy_docs:
  url: /docs/:filename.pdf
  param: { module: default, action: display_pdf }
```

Then create an action to output the pdf:

```
  public function executeDisplayPdf()
  {
    $filename = $this->getRequestParameter('filename');

    $path_to_pdf = 'http://'.sfConfig::get('website_hostname').'/uploads/'.'/'.$filename.'.pdf';

    //create the response object
    $this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public', true);
    $this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/pdf');
    $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders();
    $this->getResponse()->setContent(readfile($path_to_pdf));

    //set up the view
    $this->setLayout(false);
    sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);

    return sfView::NONE;
  }
```

Comment: Glad to see that the blog entry was helpful :)